# Outputting data with ob_flush produces notice

Tags: php

I have a script that takes around 400s to complete. I am also currently using this function to output logs as the script loops through certain tasks.

```
function CLI_LOG($message){
    echo $message."\n";
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    ob_start(); 
}
```

And at the top of my `script.php` I have `ob_start();`

This works fine in the browser! Although when I run it on the command line using

`php -f script.php`

Every time I use the function I receive these two errors

`Notice: ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in script.php on line 127`

`PHP Notice:  ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in script.php on line 127`

The line 127 holds this piece of code

`ob_flush();`

I have even tried to suppress these errors using both `error_reporting(0);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` with no luck?

Comment: It pretty clearly says that there is **no buffer to flush.** You're trying to flush a buffer which doesn't exist, because none is open at the time you call `ob_flush`.

Comment: @deceze Sorry, I should have said that I have `ob_start();` at the top of my page. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a ob_flush() after a ob_end_flush() but ob_end_flush() already ends the buffer... so you have no more buffer.

```
function CLI_LOG($message){
    echo $message."\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

No need to start another buffer if you don't end the previous one.